# Redirect domain to www Javascript

Tags: javascript, redirect

**How i can redirect a domain to www in javascript**

**http://example.com to http://www.example.com**

and this is my code

```
<script>
if(/http:\/\/?example\.com/.test(document.referrer)) {
   window.location = "http://www.example.com/";
}
</script>
```

thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use `window.location.hostname` because `document.referrer` doesn't always work. If you don't believe me, try it in the inspector of this page. So as you will have something like the one of @Chris :

```
if(window.location.hostname === "example.com") {
   window.location.hostname = "www.example.com";
}
```

And avoid regex when it's possible

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
if(window.location.hostname === "example.com") {
   window.location.hostname = "www.example.com";
}
</script>
```